# Check using stored procedure is better or select command in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, oracle9i

I am re-engineering an Oracle form to asp.net page.

My question is that is there any difference if I use a stored procedure and run a cursor or by using a `OracleAdapter` fetch data with select command?

Solution 1:

```
call a cursor in backend (stored procedure)
```

Solution 2:

```
write select command

OracleAdaptor oap = new OracleAdaptor();
oap.selectCommand = new OracleCommand();
oap.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select v_name from table1 where v_name="+textbox1.text;
oap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Well in my point of view both are select command, would you help me? I want to chose one of them.

Which one is *faster* and *more recommended?*

My Oracle database is 9i.

Comment: There is only one way to find out for your use case - benchmark it. Repeat it many times (say million) so you can get more accurate numbers.

Comment: Any one have practical practice or read about it any where? because in oracle form it is recommended use cursur instead of select command but based on my ASP.net experiance I used to write select command in asp.net pages and fetch data, I want to know my work is correct or not I should use cursor.

Comment: Stored procedure caches execution plan for query on database, so in most cases, in consecutive run, using stored procedure must be better than using direct command from Asp.net page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stopwatch` class for this purpose.

you can start stopwatch before executing command or stored procedure.

And stop after execution.

This will return you time requiered for execution.

```
Try
{
    // Create new stopwatch
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();

    //command execution

    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
    stopwatch.Elapsed);

}
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, your answer is from speed point of view is useful, but my question is also about functionality of cursor as well. because in form if we use select command instead of Cursor we receive error sometime.

Comment: your question header and content differs a lot.